# Copy attachment's from one document to another in same database

Tags: couchdb

I want to copy an attachment from one document to another without overwriting the fields of the document in the same database.

> For instance:
>
> I have two JSON documents having attachments as below,

```
{
    "_id": "61d670a97e0e02cf13a43ed44101889f",
    "_rev": "7-53440461b95c28ebf2cdf939476e3303",
    "_attachments": {
        "test1.apk": {...}
    },
    name : "test"
}

{
    "_id": "0ff12a4b0079e9cfb413cc22f6008b41",
    "_rev": "3-787f15b3fcce621e6aaaf0055f152e5f",
    "_attachments": {
        "test2.apk": {...}
    },
    name: "test2"
}
```

> I want to copy the attachments from both documents i.e **test1.apk** and
>   **test2.apk** to third document as shown below,

```
{
    "_id": "45d57q79z20ew2cf13a43ed44101887c",
    "_rev": "1-93640461b95c28ebf2cdf939476e3305",
    "_attachments": {
        "copyTest1.apk": {...},
        "copyTest2.apk": {...}
    },
    name : "test1-test2"
}
```

So my question is

> 1) Is it possible to do it in CouchDb with its internal/update operations?
>
> 2) If Yes then is it possible to rename the attachments while copying?

Also while going through couchDb documents I came across [**Copy**](http://couchdb-13.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/documents/#copy-db-doc) command of couchdb which copies the document based on revision's but it also overwrites the other fields.